# Custom made constraint in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, indexing, constraints, primary-key, unique

I have a table with the following fields and sample records:

```
sample_date  customer   active
 25/12/2010   12356       N
 01/12/2012   12356       N
 05/11/2013   12356       N
 05/07/2014   12356       Y
```

I want to enforce 2 constraints:

- Just one "ACTIVE" set to "Y" per CUSTOMER (but, several "N" are allowed)
- Just one SAMPLE_DATE per CUSTOMER

So that it refuses to save any other line for this customer with a ACTIVE value of "Y" unless the old one is first set to 'N'.

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *Note*: how about `boolean` for your `active` column? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-boolean.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Just one "ACTIVE" set to "Y" per CUSTOMER (but, several "N" are allowed)*

```
create unique index ix_only_one_active 
   on the_table (customer) 
   where active = 'Y';
```

This will allow any number of rows to be inserted for a customer with an active flag other than `'Y'`. You might want to also add a check constraint on that column

---

> *Just one SAMPLE_DATE per CUSTOMER*

```
create unique index ix_unique_sample_date_customer 
     on the_table (customer, sample_date);
```

---

<sup>P.S.: I agree with pozs' comment: it would be better/cleaner to define the `active` column as `boolean`</sup>

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I use the field as boolean, I just didn't show in the sample to keep it simple. But the 2 different constraints worked perfectly to what I wanted to do! Thanks a lot!